# How to manually update isc bind9

Tags: dns

With the rate of vulnerabilities these days, its difficult to keep ahead. There have been no package updates for the DNS bind9 recently but there are plenty of vulnerabilities. Can someone please assist with a "How-To" for a manual installation of the latest stable release of Bind9 from ISC?

Comment: What security updates have you found in bind9 that Canonical haven't picked up on? Can you name any specific CVEs so that I can file bugs on them? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The bind9 package is in main, which means that Canonical are committed to providing security updates for it until the [end-of-life of any particular release](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases). Note that security updates are generally backported, so you won't necessarily be able to tell what updates are included from just the version number. Instead, you should check the [changelog](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bind9/+changelog) or search for the [CVE](http://cve.mitre.org/) that concerns you using [Launchpad's CVE search feature](https://launchpad.net/bugs/cve).

Users who care about keeping their versions up-to-date should stay updated via the official security updates.

Building the package from source will work, but you will need to watch upstream security notices and keep up-to-date yourself. One big reason to use a distribution package is to save you this trouble, since the distribution vendor does this for you.